# Tub leaking at the supply line

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

Today I tried to replace my tub faucet since the old one was dripping out of the front. The new one looks great! Unfortunately, it seems to drip at the supply pipe. The following picture shows the back of the tub, where the supply line connects.

[image]

I have circled where it is leaking--in between the ring which fastens the faucet to the tub and the part which connects the supply pipe to the faucet shank. It is leaking on both sides. Tightening the connection and adding more thread seal tape did not help. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (or someone) has used pipe thread couplings to adapt the 3/4" faucet inlet to those supply lines, this is not (IMO) the best practice.

Stainless braided flex supply lines with a 3/4" connector are available, specifically for your application. Decorative covers (generally called "shrouds") are also available with which to hide the supply lines if you don't like their look.

[image]

Specifications:
Overall Length: 37"
Rough-in Connection: 1/2"
Faucet Connection: 3/4"
Braided Stainless Steel

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Can you link to the shrouds? My google searches only yielded add-ons for sinks.

Comment: http://www.clawfootbathtubwarehouse.com/ClawfootSupplyLines.htm